# How to assign value to 2d array in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I want to assign value to 2d array in for loop
This is my code

```python
num = 0
n = 3
arr = [[0] * n] * n

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        arr[i][j] = num
        num +=1
```

The output I expected is

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
```

But actual output is

```
[6, 7, 8]
[6, 7, 8]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
arr = [[0] * n] * n
```

It creates n copies of list. So, when you make a change in one list, all others are changed as well. You can change it to something like this:

```py
arr = [[0 for j in n] for i in n]
```